# Python read numbers in text file to list to calculate mean

Tags: python

I have a file with a lot of numbers and I want to try to read it in python into a list of a list. Then calculate its mean or sum or whatever.

Here is my text file:

```
   1,2,5349,2398,19,3450
   10,95,201,5943,234,2319482,12
```

then here is my code:

```
def ReadList(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as numbers:
        datalist = [] 
        for line in numbers:
            datalist.append(line.strip().split(' '))
    return datalist
```

but my results turn up as datalist = ['1,2,5349....3450'],['10,95...,12'] they have the apostraphe at the beinning and the end, and I can't calculate the mean with it. I have tried to use:
                     `datalist.appent(int(line.strip().split(' ')))`already and it doesn't make the data into numbers but adds some other errors.

EDIT: The data seem okay now that I changed it to `datalist.append([int(x) for x in line.strip().split(',')])`.

But I can't calculate the mean when my method is

```
numbers = ReadList('data.txt')

total = 0.0
for num in numbers:
     total = total + num
return total/len(nums)
```

the same errors still appear:`"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'"`

My goal is to have it as a few separate list of a list and calculate each separate list's means and then display it in a column for example:

```
List# Mean
1     (Mean value of the first list( 1,2,5349,2398,19,3450))
2     (Mean value of the second list(10,95,201,5943,234,2319482,12))
```

Comment: You have to split by comma and then convert to int.

Comment: Please fix he code formatting

Comment: I misunderstood your problem. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: @Onggia, I just update my answer based on your edit. Please take a look and accept if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to split at `","` and not `" "` so make this change

`line.strip().split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two operations here, first one you have to split the list with `','` and after that you have to transform the string to int.

you can do that using:

```
datalist.append([ int(x) for x in line.strip().split(',') ])
```

this code will split the string, transform the string to int, and after that append to the datalist variable.

EDIT:
you have update your question, so here is the rest of my answer:
There are two errors in the block that you calculate the mean, the first one is that you are iterating in a list of lists, so you have to go through both of the itens, the second is that you are using the wrong value. You are calculating the len of num, you should get the len of numbers. this is what will be your final code:

```
numbers = ReadList('data.txt')
    means = []
    for line in numbers:
         total = 0.0
         for num in line:
              total = total + num
          means.append(total/len(numbers))
    return means
```

Comment: I also have another question regarding list in a list, what if I want to slice off the last number on both list? How would I code it. I have been searching around but the multiaxle explanations are not really clear to me.

Comment: Also, I just found out that the result from this code end up adding the first list(they continue to add the previous list to make a new mean that is including all the data altogether)

Comment: @Onggia, I just edit my answer to resolve the issue that you point.

Comment: @Onggia if you want to remove the last item of a list, you can do it with the [:-1] operand, this will get all the itens except the last